# If repeaters share the same call sign are they "Connected"

Tags: repeater

Newbe here,

I was looking through repeaters in my area and I noticed that there were a few repeaters that shared the same call sign(even though they run on different frequencies).  Does this mean that the repeaters are connected and transmitting on one will transmit on all?

For example:  [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't assume that repeaters with the same call are connected.  What the call sign denotes is that they're owned and operated by the same operator or club -- for instance, in my area, there are multiple repeaters on W4NC (Forsyth Amateur Radio Club), but calling through the one on Sauratown Mountain doesn't let you talk to someone tuned to the one on Wake Forest Baptist Hospital.  Same repeater call sign (on different frequencies; there are locations where you can reach and hear both), but not connected in any way.

Comment: Thanks you for the information. I would think if they were owned by the same club that the would want to connect them(there are 5 with that call sign in my area).  Maybe there's some reason why they want them separate?  I guess I could ask on the channel...I'm getting my license Saturday :).

Comment: Good luck with the test!  There are reasons to network repeaters (All the KF4OVA machines in my area are connected, on 6m, 2m, and 440 band), and reasons not to (old hardware, expense for landline or internet connections, additional maintenance).

Answer (score 3):

Different frequencies and different locations ... many clubs operate multiple repeaters to give their members access in extended areas. They are NOT necessarily connected.

MGRA (Middle GA) has several, two of them CAN be linked via EchoLink; but normally are not. The have the same club call sign.